# How do I disable colors in LaTeX output generated from sphinx?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

When I build the LaTeX file generated from sphinx, the TOC entries, and section headers are blue.  Is there an easy way to disable coloring these items?  If not, is there an easy way to make them black instead?  My goal is to print the document on a non-color printer, and the TOC and headings do not look as dark as the rest of the text when I do so.

I would like to make one change that applies to the whole document if possible.

Note: I am using the howto document class.

---

### Update

Thanks to ddbeck's input, I took a closer look at `sphinx.sty` which defines the colors that I needed to change.  I set (created) the **latex_elements** dictionary in `conf.py` as follows:

```
mypreamble ='''
\\pagenumbering{arabic}
\\definecolor{TitleColor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\\definecolor{InnerLinkColor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
'''
latex_elements = {
    'papersize':'letterpaper',
    'pointsize':'11pt',
    'preamble':mypreamble
    }
```

This worked out exactly as I wanted it.  Thanks ddbeck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add LaTeX by using the `latex_elements['preamble']` configuration option. If you change the value of that key, you can override Sphinx's normal LaTeX. [The docs](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/config.html#confval-latex_elements) on this option aren't particularly illuminating, however. You may find [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/browse_thread/thread/9938efe47b28e492) from [sphinx-dev](http://groups.google.com/group/sphinx-dev/) a bit more helpful; it has more detail on how that might be used, as well as some good links for learning about LaTex (if that's something you need to get black and white output). Finally, it might help to take a look at the [default `.cls` and `.sty` files](http://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/tip/sphinx/texinputs/).

Comment: +1 The link to the default .cls and .sty files provided the information needed to set the color of the section headers.

Comment: Thanks to your input, I was able to figure it out (updated question to show what I did)